# How to enter a web page , save the paramter response and use it to enter another page with this pramter

Tags: jmeter

i need your help with a problem i encounter with jmeter
i need to create the following:

Enter a web page

Save from the response of the page a parameter

Use this parameter to enter another page

someone have an answer to my problem
thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bit generic, but here goes:

1. HTTP sampler to make the request
2. Regular Expression Extractor (or Xpath) post processor to get the
   data you need from the response.
3. HTTP sampler using variable from step 2

Links:

Regular Expressions
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm

Xpath
http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0

Answer (score 0):

Ophir is correct.

Extract the parameter using regular expression extractor and the parameter value can be put into next request using the reference name specified in regular expression extractor.

eg: https://www.example.com/search?q=${reference},

Hope these links will help you.
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html

http://chinmaybrahma022.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/jmeter-regular-expression-extractor-postprocessor/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_regular_expressions.htm